# Export an Email intent

Tags: intents

[Wire](https://github.com/wireapp/wire/issues/391) only [accepts bug reports via email intents](https://github.com/wireapp/wire/issues/394), which breaks if you never give your Android device email access.

Are there apps which could capture an email intent and save it for sending from another device?

Comment: I would try an mail app like FairMail and then try to configure a non-existing POP3 Mail Account. As POP3 only requires server communication for sending or receiving messages you should be able to save the Wire generated mail to your local draft folder.